# Bootstrap datepicker validating date

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, typescript

I am using Bootstrap datepicker and I have run into trouble when it comes to validation of the date. User can type the date in or pick it from pop-up datepicker. For some reason the format of this date is yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz. 

For validation I use simple function with moment.js (written in typescript):

```
validateDate = (date: any) => {
        return (
            moment(date, 'dd/MM/YYYY', true).isValid() ||
            moment(date, 'd/MM/YYYY', true).isValid()  ||
            moment(date, 'dd-MM-YYYY', true).isValid() ||
            moment(date, 'd-MM-YYYY', true).isValid()  ||
            moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-d', true).isValid()  ||
            moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-dd', true).isValid() 
        );
    }
```

Datepicker settings:

```
dateOptions = {
        startingDay: 1,
        showWeeks: 'false'
    };

    format = 'dd/MM/yyyy';
    altInputFormats = ['dd/MM/yyyy', 'dd-MM-yyyy', 'd-MM-yyyy'];
```

Since it is Angular app, I trigger validation within ng-change.
Is there a way to set datepicker date format to only date without time part? I tried taking substring from this value by using index of T, but it didn't work.